# How to split a dictionary into "n" parts

Tags: c#, linq

I need to split my dictionary using LINQ expression. I need to split into two parts. Could somebody help me?

```
var myDictionary = new Dictionary<int, int>();
var halfOfDictionary = myDictionary.ToDictionary(...)
```

Comment: Split it how? You want to get the keys in one collection and the values in another (you don't need Linq for that)? Or you want to construct 2 new dictionaries containing some part of the original pairs based on some condition? Please be more specific.

Comment: What is your intent for doing so? There may be better ways of achieving what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// remove OrderBy if ordering is not important
var ordered = dictionary.OrderBy(kv => kv.Key);
var half = dictionary.Count/2;
var firstHalf = ordered.Take(half).ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.Value);
var secondHalf = ordered.Skip(half).ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.Value);
```

Comment: This assumes (dictionary.Count % 2 == 0). Unless C# is different with integer division

Comment: @BradenBrown I don't see a problem with the division. The div result is an int. The same number is taken and skipped (no off-by-one mistake).